# Facebox + Blueprintcss looks great in Firefox, falls apart in IE 7

Tags: internet-explorer, facebox

Not sure how to fix this or where to look in resolving how Facebook content that has been laid-out using Blueprintcss looks so poorly spaced in IE7.

Is there any guidance on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you include your ie.css file?

Did you add the following line at the top of the page to ensure that FBML renders properly in IE.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Comment: not sure if this is the right answer, gave up but will give it points since it does render some important information for this problem.